# Modal is coming back undefined in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Google is giving me the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined" in response to my ui-bootstrap module. I've been using other ui-bootsrap directives fine.

Am I not declaring the modal dependency correctly?

```
angular.module('ireg').directive('study', function (studyFactory) {
return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {             
        objectid:'@objectid'
    },
    templateUrl: '/ireg/components/study/study.html',

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, $modal) {

        scope.openMilestonesDialog = function () {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: '/ireg/components/add-milestones/addMilestonesDialog.html',
                controller: '/ireg/components/add-milestones/addMilestonesDialogController.js',
                size: lg
            });
        };

    }//end of link

}
});

angular.module('ireg').controller('addMilestonesDialogController', function ($scope, $modalInstance, studyId) {

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
 };


});
```

Comment: I think `size: lg` is causing the issue. Try to change it with `size: 'lg'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include $modal service in your `directive` function instead of `link` function:

```
angular.module('ireg').directive('study', function (studyFactory, $modal) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {             
            objectid:'@objectid'
        },
        templateUrl: '/ireg/components/study/study.html',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.openMilestonesDialog = function () {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: '/ireg/components/add-milestones/addMilestonesDialog.html',
                    controller: '/ireg/components/add-milestones/addMilestonesDialogController.js',
                    size: 'lg'
                });
            };

        }//end of link

    }

});
```

And yes, Alberto I.N.J. is right, you should set `size` attribute as string.

Comment: Thankyou. May I ask why it belongs there over the other location?

Comment: Yes, sure. Can you provide some code where you're using ui-bootstrap directives? As I remember, only modal directive requires $modal service as dependency injection in your directive. All others directives work fine after including 'ui.bootstrap' module to your app.

Answer (score 1):

You should inject $model into directive itself and change lg to 'lg'

```
angular.module('ireg').directive('study', function (studyFactory, $modal) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {             
            objectid:'@objectid'
        },
        templateUrl: '/ireg/components/study/study.html',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.openMilestonesDialog = function () {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: '/ireg/components/add-milestones/addMilestonesDialog.html',
                    controller: '/ireg/components/add-milestones/addMilestonesDialogController.js',
                    size: 'lg'
                });
            };

        }//end of link

    }

});
```